# To assign the values to the same name in different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in python. I have multiple same Name in the column df2, let say I don't want to drop the duplicate Name in df2.

How do I  assign the values (Marks) from df1 to the same Name in df2 in different rows?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['rumul', 'rahul',
                             'ravi', 'imran'],
                    'Marks': [5, 20, 8, 12]})
 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['rumul', 'rahul',
                             'rahul', 'ravi',
                             'imran','ravi', 'ravi','imran','rahul','ravi'],
                    'Marks': ['','','','','','','','','','']})
```

df1

| Name | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| rumul | 5 |
| rahul | 20 |
| ravi | 8 |
| imran | 12 |

df2

| Name | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| rumul |  |
| rahul |  |
| rahul |  |
| ravi |  |
| imran |  |
| ravi |  |
| ravi |  |
| imran |  |
| rahul |  |
| ravi |  |

**The expected output:**

| Name | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| rumul | 5 |
| rahul | 20 |
| rahul | 20 |
| ravi | 8 |
| imran | 12 |
| ravi | 8 |
| ravi | 8 |
| imran | 12 |
| rahul | 20 |
| ravi | 8 |

Comment: I voted to reopen because 2 answers does not use `merge`. Merge is probably "too much" for this problem IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a map to avoid the need of `merge()`. Because merge would add an extra column and not necessarily overwrite it.

```
df2['Marks'] = df2['Name'].map(df1.set_index('Name').to_dict()['Marks'])
```

This would output:

```
    Name  Marks
0  rumul      5
1  rahul     20
2  rahul     20
3   ravi      8
4  imran     12
5   ravi      8
6   ravi      8
```

For the same output, you can use pandas `replace()`

Comment: Agree with you about `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Indexing` operations:

```
>>> df1.set_index('Name').reindex(df2['Name']).reset_index()
    Name  Marks
0  rumul      5
1  rahul     20
2  rahul     20
3   ravi      8
4  imran     12
5   ravi      8
6   ravi      8
7  imran     12
8  rahul     20
9   ravi      8
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple 1-liner with `merge`:

```
df2[["Name"]].merge(df1, on="Name", how="left").rename(columns={"Marks_y": "Marks"})
```

```
    Name  Marks
0  rumul      5
1  rahul     20
2  rahul     20
3   ravi      8
4  imran     12
5   ravi      8
6   ravi      8
7  imran     12
8  rahul     20
9   ravi      8
```